# no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer on nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested-attributes, strong-parameters

I am having issues with editing nested attributes. I'm getting this error :

```
no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer
```

event.rb:

```
Class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :event_joins, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :event_joins
end
```

events_controller.rb :

```
private
   def event_params
     params.require(:event).permit(event_joins_attributes: [:duration]) 
   end
```

_form.html.erb :

```
 =f.fields_for :event_joins_attributes do |a|
    =number_field_tag 'event[event_joins_attributes][duration]'
 end
```

If I change my `params` before permission with

```
params[:event][:event_joins_attributes][:duration] = params[:event][:event_joins_attributes][:duration].to_i
```

I have the following error:

```
no implicit conversion of String into Integer
```

I've read a lot of posts about nested attributes for mass-assignment but nothing works.
Here is part of posts I've read.

[strong-parameters-permit-all-attributes-for-nested-attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810838/strong-parameters-permit-all-attributes-for-nested-attributes)

[rails-4-strong-parameters-nested-objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436741/rails-4-strong-parameters-nested-objects)

[whitelisted attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24475600/3550170)

Of course, I don't want to do

```
params.require(:event).permit!
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to change this

```
=f.fields_for :event_joins_attributes do |a|
   =number_field_tag 'event[event_joins_attributes][duration]'
end
```

to

```
=f.fields_for :event_joins do |a|
   =a.number_field :duration
end
```

So that you can have your `event_params` unchanged.

***Imp note:***

Also always permit `:id` in the `event_params` for the ***Update*** to work correctly.

```
def event_params
  params.require(:event).permit(:id, event_joins_attributes: [:id, :duration]) 
end
```

Comment: I get the same error : no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer after changing the view and adding the ids in the strong paramets

Comment: @Snake You don't need to do this `params[:event][:event_joins_attributes][:duration] = params[:event][:event_joins_attributes][:duration].to_i`