# Rails 5.1 - JSON parameter is permitted but still prints as unpermitted in the log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parameters, whitelist

In Rails 4 [here is the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17810838/strong-parameters-permit-all-attributes-for-nested-attributes) about HOW to do this. What I would like to know is, although this works, WHY does the log still complain?

In Rails 5.1.3 I have a JSON column (`letterhead`) as one of my model attributes (and inside that json is a hash with various attributes that I don't care about whitelisting). I just want to permit/whitelist the column itself.

**Note on Rails 5.1.4**

There is a Rails way to do this in 5.1.4, see [this commit](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/e86524c0c5a26ceec92895c830d1355ae47a7034).
There is a rather long discussion [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454) on github about this. In Rails 5.1.4 it is simply this:

```
def account_params
  params.require(:account).permit(:id, :name, :plan_id, letterhead: {})
end
```

The `:letterhead` parameter is permitted, no error shows in the log and the model saves. But obviously it allows arbitrary input inside that parameter, so *use with care.*

If you did want to restrict which hash keys were allowed inside such a parameter, then you can also whitelist those, like this for example:

```
def account_params
  params.require(:account).permit(:id, :name, :plan_id, letterhead: [:address, :logo, :contact_info])
end
```

This now prevents *any other arbitrary keys* inside `:letterhead` since I have explicitly only permitted these 3 - `:address, :logo, :contact_info`

**Rails 5.1.3 (and earlier)**

I can permit this column using either of the following (see the linked discussion for other possible options also):

**Option 1**

```
def account_params
  params.require(:account).permit(:id, :name, :plan_id, :letterhead).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted[:letterhead] = params[:account].fetch(:letterhead, ActionController::Parameters.new).permit!
  end
end
```

**Option 2**

```
def account_params
  params.require(:account).permit(:id, :name, :plan_id, :letterhead).tap do |whitelisted|
    whitelisted[:letterhead] = params[:account][:letterhead].permit!
  end
end
```

In both cases the model saves but in the log it still says "unpermitted parameters :letterhead"

1. Why is still saying that when I have explicitly permitted it?
2. Also, is there any real difference between Option 1 and Option 2?

**EDIT**

Data is like this:

```
{"id"=>"a61151b8-deed-4efa-8cad-da1b143196c9", 
"plan_id"=>"1dc49acf-3111-4030-aea1-7db259b53a51", 
"name"=>"Test Account 1", 
"is_active"=>true, 
"letterhead"=>{"left"=>"", "center"=>"", "right"=>""}, 
"created_by"=>nil, 
"updated_by"=>nil, 
"created_at"=>"2017-10-14T19:05:40.197Z", 
"updated_at"=>"2017-10-20T15:14:08.194Z"}
```

Comment: Hows yr incoming data look like ?

Comment: @7urkm3n I added an edit showing the data

Comment: what kind an error do you see (complain) ? Can you post yr log and method of use ?

Comment: @7urkm3n I upgraded to latest Rails to solve it, so can no longer post anything. The log said "unpermitted parameters:" then listed them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Why is still saying that when I have explicitly permitted it?

The log comes from [`#unpermitted_parameters!`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5.1.3/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L855) which is called by [`#permit`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5.1.3/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/strong_parameters.rb#L534). All this happens *before* the call to `#tap`.

## Is there any real difference between Option 1 and Option 2?

The difference boils down to

```
params[:account].fetch(:letterhead, ActionController::Parameters.new).permit!
```

vs

```
params[:account][:letterhead].permit!
```

The latter will result in `NoMethodError` if `:letterhead` isn't passed because `params[:account][:letterhead]` will return `nil`. The former returns an empty hash of parameters instead.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer to both questions. However the last paragraph does not make sense. You say the latter will result in NoMethodError...will return nil. It cannot return both? Also is the final sentence finished - it ends with a square bracket?

Comment: @rmcsharry, the last paragraph was a type due to my Kinesis ;-) What I had in mind is the difference between `#[]` and `#fetch`. If `:letterhead` isn't passed then `params[:account][:letterhead]` is `nil` and `nil` doesn't define `#permit!`.

Comment: I see now, thanks for clarifying. You deserve the bonus :)

Comment: Thank you, @rmcsharry. I appreciate it.