# Rails 4 strong parameters param not found error with carrierwave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm having trouble with carrierwave and rails 4 strong parameters. I have a very simple model with a carrier wave upload button. I'd like to show an error message if someone submits the upload form without choosing a file to upload.

Right now, I get a `param not found:photo` error with this message:

```
  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def photo_params
      params.require(:photo).permit(:image)
    end
```

This error is happening because Rails 4's strong parameters is requiring that the image parameter be present to submit the form, but it's not there because the user hasn't selected an image.

I can't figure out a way to work around this and have it redirect to the same action and display an error message.

Is there a way to do this with strong parameters?

Here's the development log when I try to use the form without a photo selected:
https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/09b6166ce1af6ca6c833

And here's the development log when I choose a photo and it uploads successfully:
https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/1f1e584f56aef15e7af1

Other relevant files:
* models/photo.rb - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/95c54a5df4e4ee6518da
* controllers/photos_controller.rb - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/c0723e6dc5478b0f914d
* uploaders/image_uploader.rb - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/5e43f6524734991773ae
* views/photos/index.html.erb - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/a8c4c808e5e8a802933b
* views/photos/_form.html.erb - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/cd0fd518c1b47d9bfb62
* initializers/carrierwaver.rb - https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/49e04fa1dda891dd108b

Comment: Can you provide your `_form` code?

Comment: Sure. Forgot to include that https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/cd0fd518c1b47d9bfb62

Comment: And can you show your post code to the controller? It seems that the params does not include the photo key.  To simply debug you could do `params.permit!` to allow anything, or to simplify the process you can do something along the lines of `params.permit(:image)`

Comment: I have this line in my photos_controller.rb (see above in the original question): `params.require(:photo).permit(:image)`. Is that not what you're suggesting?

Comment: If I switch that line to `params.permit!` I still get the same error: `param not found: photo`

Comment: If I switch that line to `params.permit(:image)` then I get an `Image can't be blank` validation error message, but no rails error. It renders the correct template with the `image can't be blank` message. That seems like progress, but when I try to upload an image through the form, it gives me the same validation error.

Comment: What is the form actually posting to the controller? There should be some kind of hash being output in the server logs when it's posted. Can you post that here?

Comment: Yeah, just added it to my question https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/09b6166ce1af6ca6c833

Comment: What does it look like when you post with a file?

Comment: it posts fine. the dev log looks like this: https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/1f1e584f56aef15e7af1

Comment: To solve the `Image can't be blank` issue, you may need to specify `storage :file` in the uploader.

Comment: Hmmm. that's not an option because heroku won't let me host the images on the server. They have to go to S3. I guess I was wondering if there's a way around this so that the user doesn't see a nasty rails error and gets some sort of useful error message.

Comment: I was under the impression that you were doing this locally. You can set it to use `storage :fog` in that case. Either way, I think you need to set storage to something. Just make sure you have everything configured for S3 and that `fog` is in your Gemfile, too. You could also set it conditionally like `storage Rails.env.production? ? :fog : :file`

Comment: I am using s3 in development to more closely match my production environment. You're right I was missing storage :fog in image_uploader.rb. I added that but I'm still getting the same `param not found: photo` error.

Comment: Does it work now if you do `params.permit(:image)`? No more `Image can't be blank` message?

Comment: If I switch my photos controller to this `params.permit(:image)` (https://gist.github.com/leemcalilly/88839f37eb7ce0f3deba), I get an Image can't be blank error if an image is present and when it is not present.

Comment: not sure if you've seen this link, if you do I'll remove it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483963/rails-4-0-strong-parameters-nested-attributes-with-a-key-that-points-to-a-hash

Comment: No I haven't seen that link. That looks like the right path. I'll try it.

Comment: yeah I'm not able to get that to work

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The [rails guides provides the solution](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#more-examples). Use the `fetch` method in the same way as the `require` method. **Note a second argument:** it supplies the default value. So, if the `params[:photo]` would not be found, the default value *(an empty hash, as of the example below)* will be returned:

```
params.fetch(:photo, {})
```

Comment: Excellent -- this is exactly what I was looking for. I don't see why this isn't the best practice advertised.

Answer (score 12):

Sorry spotted this is bit late ,Ok now looking at your form code which look something like this

```
<%= form_for @photo, :html => {:multipart => true}  do |f| %>
  <% if @photo.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@photo.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this photo from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @photo.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <fieldset>
    <legend>Upload a Photo</legend>
    <div class="field">
      <%= f.file_field :image %>
    </div>              
   </fieldset>  

   <%= f.submit "Upload Photo", :class => "btn btn-small" %>
<% end %>
```

Now there this is  not a problem with `rails` or `carrierwave` or `strong_parameter` it is something how `html` works . It like this, if you have `file` input and if `nothing` is attached to it the `name` and `value` pair is not sent to the server by `HTML` think of it something like `checkbox` or `disabled` field

Now since your form only contain 
 `<%= f.file_field :image %>`
and it does not contain any other field (attributes of photo model)

therefore the `photo` hash would not get constructed when the `file` input `does not` contain any attachment

which is evident in your log as well

#### Parameter (without attachment attached) =>

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"IvOieBvxdA6qzVKrt1dYBuCXlt+uuWCyWjUAuTK0XEU=", "commit"=>"Upload Photo"}
```

#### Parameter (with attachment attached) =>

```
 {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"I4O0w+Wk8nJaD6HJRSC+FfuAip5NVE6TkCUFDEN+sW0=", "photo"=>{"image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fc730b5de08 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/0m/n32lgww55vzf5pfc4kh17gm00000gr/T/RackMultipart20130801-32602-1nj6u2b>, @original_filename="bag.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"photo[image]\"; filename=\"bag.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}, "commit"=>"Upload Photo"}
```

now you can see the difference between the two and that the difference is the reason of your error because in

**1st case**

`params[:photo].present?` => false

**2nd case**

`params[:photo].present?` => true

and hence when you do this `params.require(:photo).permit(:image)` the code throws the errors

because of the line mention that `.require(:photo)` which is `not` present in `params`

#### Solution:-

Perhaps you can do something like this

```
   def photo_params
     if params[:photo].present?
      params.require(:photo).permit(:image)
     end
   end
```

#### Conclusion :-

It not  anyone fault  because that  is how the `HTML` work if `no` attachment `no` `name=value` pair submitted to server and because of which `photo` params is not sent to server hence the hash is does not have them and hence strong parameter throws the error

Hope this help

Comment: This is very helpful and gets at the heart of the problem, but I think I need to accept Mrjaco12's answer as a more canonical approach since it's documented in the rails guides. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: what if we need "if photo_params[:image].present?" in this case photo_params is false, and [:image] hash is nil. so we cant check for present?

Comment: @Kirka121 Sorry man I seriously don't remember much on this but just a question how come photo_params will be `false`