# Best way to handle missing required params with StrongParameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I have an `Upload` ActiveModel class that has one attribute: `filename`.  Since there's only one attribute, leaving the field blank on the form ends up raising an error when using the following code in my controller:

```
class UploadsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @upload = Upload.new(upload_params)
    # ...
  end

  private

  def upload_params
    params.require(:upload).permit(:filename)
  end
end
```

The best workaround I've come up with is to `rescue` in the `upload_params` method, e.g.:

```
def upload_params
  params.require(:upload).permit(:filename) rescue ActionController::Parameters.new
end
```

Alternatively, I suppose I could add a hidden field to ensure that the `filename` field is always set to something no matter what, e.g.:

```
= simple_form_for upload do |f|
  = f.input :filename, as: :hidden, input_html: { value: '' }
  = f.input :filename, as: :file
  = f.submit 'Upload'
```

Is there a better way of handling the user not filling out any of the form attributes?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Figures that I find [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17937112/rails-4-strong-parameters-param-not-found-error-with-carrierwave) immediately after posting my question. :)

It looks like the `ActionController::StrongParameters#fetch` method does what's needed, e.g.:

```
params.fetch(:upload, {}).permit(:filename)
```