# Rails 4 + Strong params: How to permit everything?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cocoon-gem

Due to the complexity of my model relationships and the flexibility in my form, I require that strong params takes all keys for `params[:variants]`.

I'm using the cocoon gem for nested forms, and it generates a random string of digits for every new entry like so:

```
>> params[:variants]
=> {"1401200245834"=>{"size"=>"M", "price"=>"0.00", "measurements"=>"", "sku"=>""}}
```

The `1401200245834` is random, so I can't stick it into my permitted params. How would I allow for everything under the `:variants` key in my params hash?

Comment: Not sure so just a comment: try adding the permit method at the end like: permit! And I think this is not recommended.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14483963/rails-4-0-strong-parameters-nested-attributes-with-a-key-that-points-to-a-hash

Check out this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this paragraph from the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters) is relevant:

To whitelist an entire hash of parameters, the `permit!` method can be used:

```
params.require(:variants).permit!
```

This will mark the :variants parameters hash and any subhash of it permitted. Extreme care should be taken when using permit! as it will allow all current and future model attributes to be mass-assigned.