# Rails Strong Parameters - allow deep nested hashes within array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, hash, strong-parameters

How to permit/white-list deep-nested hashes with very un-regular (impossible to declare) structure.

Example:

```
{"widgets" => [
  {
    "id" => 75432,
    "conversion_goal_id" => 1331,
    "options" => {"form_settings"=>{"formbuilder-bg-color"=>"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)", "font-size"=>"14px", "form-field-depth"=>"42px"}, "linkedWidget"=>""},
    "type" => "formbuilder-widget"
  },
  {
    "id" => 75433,
    "conversion_goal_id" => nil,
    "options" => {"width"=>"200px", "height"=>"185px", "display"=>"block", "left"=>313, "top"=>152, "position"=>"absolute"},
    "type" => "social-sharing-widget"
  },
  {},
]}
```

So `options` JSON/hash object doesn't have any specified structure.

It is formless.

It can be something like

```
{"width"=>"200px", "height"=>"185px", "display"=>"block", "left"=>313, "top"=>152, "position"=>"absolute"}
```

OR:

```
   {"form_settings"=>{"formbuilder-bg-color"=>"rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)", "font-size"=>"14px", "form-field-depth"=>"44px"},
    "linkedWidget"=>"",
    "required_height"=>164,
    "settings"=>
     [{"field_options"=>{"include_other_option"=>true, "size"=>"large", "view_label"=>false},
       "field_type"=>"text",
       "label"=>"Name:",
       "required"=>false,
       "asterisk"=>false,
       "textalign"=>"left"},
      {"field_options"=>{"include_other_option"=>true, "size"=>"large", "view_label"=>false},
       "field_type"=>"email",
       "label"=>"Email:",
       "required"=>false,
       "asterisk"=>false,
       "textalign"=>"left"},
      {"buttonalign"=>"left",
       "buttonbgcolor"=>"#ba7373",
       "buttonfont"=>"Old Standard TT",
       "buttonfontweight"=>"bold",
       "buttonfontstyle"=>"normal",
       "buttonfontsize"=>"18px",
       "buttonheight"=>"46px",
       "buttontxtcolor"=>"#ffffff",
       "field_options"=>{"include_other_option"=>true, "size"=>"large", "view_label"=>false},
       "field_type"=>"button",
       "label"=>"START LIVING",
       "required"=>true,
       "textalign"=>"left"}]}
```

---

Widgets node is just `Array`.

I didn't found any info how to whitelist nested attributes within array of hashes.

How to do this?

I found some info in documentation that I can specify `keys` directly,

```
page_params.permit({widgets: [:key1, :key2]})
```

But this won't work, since I want to permit ALL attributes/keys within `options` hash.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26048009/418518), also doesn't support arrays, but it allows to white-list nested objects:

```
params.require(:screenshot).permit(:title).tap do |whitelisted|
  whitelisted[:assets_attributes ] = params[:screenshot][:assets_attributes ]
end
```

---

So how I can whitelist in every single element `options` attribute (array of hashes)?

---

REPLY TO COMMENTS:

1. I need to allow everything within `options` attribute in widget node. Widget node is in `widgets` array. I still need to prevent other fields e.g. `link_text`, 'text_value' etc in array - I don't want them to be submitted.
2. I need strong parameters to whitelist used parameters and backlist not used parameters. Some parameters exist only in front-end and don't exist in back-end. If I submit everything - then I will have exception.

Comment: What are you doing with the `options` attribute? Strong params is generally used when doing mass assignment.

Comment: `options` field is used for saving OPTIONS specific to given widget. Different widget have different options, so it is formless.

Comment: Can't believe almost 4 years after this question was posted, there still doesn't seem to be a way to accomplish this with an array of deeply nested dynamic hashes.

Comment: Couldn't you just JSONify the options value on the frontend before sending and then `JSON.parse` on the backend?

Answer (score -4):

Maybe I don't follow what you're trying to do here. Strong params are to prevent a user from submitting malicious data, so it basically whitelists certain keys. If you want to allow for *everything*, what do you need strong params for?

Comment: I need to allow everything within `options` attribute in widget node. Widget node is in `widgets` array. I still need to prevent other fields e.g. `spam2` in array - I don't want them to be submitted.

Comment: I need strong parameters to whitelist used parameters and backlist not used parameters. Some parameters exist only in front-end and don't exist in back-end. If I submit everything - then I will have exception.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.