# The nested attributes is not saved in the database on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I am having a trouble that I am new with ROR and want to save some images for the organization using nest attributes or for simplicity just a String in order to try the nested attributes saving in the database but actually it is not saved.

**Organization Model**

```
class Organization < ApplicationRecord
has_secure_password
has_many :needs, dependent: :destroy
has_many :org_images, dependent: :destroy
has_many :stringas, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :org_images, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['org_image'].blank? }
accepts_nested_attributes_for :stringas, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['stringa'].blank? }
```

**Schema**

```
create_table "org_images", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "caption"
t.integer  "organization_id"
t.datetime "created_at",         null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",         null: false
t.string   "photo_file_name"
t.string   "photo_content_type"
t.integer  "photo_file_size"
t.datetime "photo_updated_at"
end

  create_table "stringas", force: :cascade do |t|
t.string   "name"
t.datetime "created_at",      null: false
t.datetime "updated_at",      null: false
t.integer  "organization_id"
end
```

**Organization Controller**

```
def new
@organization = Organization.new
3.times {@organization.org_images.build}
@organization.stringas.build # added this
end
  def organization_params
 params.require(:organization).permit(:org_name, :email, :password, :info,:image, :website_URL, :contacts, :logo_url , :password_confirmation  ,stringas_attributes:[:name,:id,:organization_id,:created_at,:updated_at] ,org_images_attributes: [:id,:organization_id,:caption, :photo_file_name, :photo_content_type,:photo_file_size,:photo_updated_at])
```

end
**Organization Form**

```
<div class= "field">
```

```
<% if builder.object.new_record? %>

  <p>
  <%= builder.label :caption, "Image Caption" %>
  <%= builder.text_field :caption %>
  </p>

  <p>
  <%= builder.label :photo, "Image File" %>
  <%= builder.file_field :photo %>
  </p>

<% end %>
```

```
<% if builder.object.new_record? %>

  <p>
  <%= builder.label :name %>
  <%= builder.text_field :name%>
  </p>

<% end %>

<% end %>
```

**Stringa and org_image Models**

```
class OrgImage < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :organization
has_attached_file :photo, :styles => { :small => "150x150>", :large =>      "320x240>" }
validates_attachment_presence :photo
validates_attachment_size :photo, :less_than => 5.megabytes
end

class Stringa < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :organization
end
```

**Organization cotroller create**

```
  def create
@organization = Organization.new(organization_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @organization.save
    session[:organization_id]=@organization.id
    format.html { redirect_to @organization, notice: 'Organization was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @organization }

  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @organization.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end
[git repository](https://github.com/MarwanAlaa94/DonationRepo/tree/marwanMerged)
**Thanks for your help**

Comment: can you show us the logs or any errors if coming, So that we can have a look why it's not getting saved.

Comment: unfortunately, it saves the organization normally with all its attributes but don't save the nested ones in their tables (In the DB browser I see the record of the organization but the tables of the nested attributes are empty , I will be very thankful if you just showed me a simple example that uses nested model saved normally.

Comment: when I tried to write accepts_nested_attributes_for :stringas only not accepts_nested_attributes_for :stringas, :reject_if => lambda { |t| t['stringa'].blank? } and filled the form of the organization again it gave me the error message "Stringas organization must exist" However I entered the field name of stringas(nested model) in the organization form so I think it is returned blank from the form !!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that problem lies in unpermitted `org_images` attributes in your `OrganizationsController`. You should add this to your `organization_parameters` method:

```
params.require(:organization).permit( ... , org_images_attributes: [:photo, :caption])
```

EDIT:

After digging a bit deeper I found out that above solution isn't always working. There's an [issue](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/9454) on this topic in Rails repo on GitHub. If you want to find nice workaround that'll suit your needs you should read it, or check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14486812/6376149) answer.